# From number of heads/tails, how can I find the probability distribution?

Tags: probability

Knowing the number of heads/tails for a given number of tosses of a coin, how can I find the probability distribution? That is, how can I find the probability that the coin is balanced, or that the coin has 70/30 unbalance and so on?

Thank you :)
João

Comment: Using statistical inference.

Comment: If you can give me some help, I'll appreciate.. Some link maybe

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=inference+coin+bias

Comment: I think that is not what you want... My guess is that you already have a model fixed (e.g. binomial distribution for the multiple number of tosses) and only want to find the chances for head and tails. Finding the whole model/distribution only from the observed outcome is rather difficult up to impossible without further information on the experiment or a giant number of data points.

Comment: Well.. computational I can get the distribution (visual). But not the formula, of course :/

Comment: "Posterior probability density function of Bayesian probability theory"
I think it is this :) Thanks kludg (and Dirk)

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach could be a **maximum likelihood** method:

- You have got a sample with size $n$ with $h$ heads and $t = n-h$ tails.
- Let $X$ be the random variable for the number of heads.
- You know that $X$ follows a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$, where $n$ is the sample size and $p$ is the unkown probability of getting a head.
- Now, choose $p$ such that the sample has **maximum likelihood**:
  $$P(X = h) = \binom n h p^h(1-p)^{n-h} = \binom n h p^h(1-p)^t \stackrel{!}{\rightarrow} \mbox{Max}$$

Comment: I've not seen the symbol consisting of an exclamation mark over a left-to-right arrow.  I assume that it means that the LHS is submitted to the maximization on the RHS, with the search space defined as the domain of $p$?

Comment: @user2153235 The meaning of this symbol is that the expression to the left of the arrow is supposed to be maximized. And you are right, here the relevant domain is the domain of $p$.

Answer (score 0):

I've read about likelihood functions for some time now, but never actually used it.  My "solution" below is actually just a Matlab/Octave implementation of `trancelocation`'s answer to this same question.  It was to dip my foot into the "likelihood" knowledge pool.

```
N=20;  % Sample size
h=15;  % Number of heads

% Possible values for probability of success 
p = 0 : 0.05 : 1.00;

if logical(exist('OCTAVE_VERSION', 'builtin')) % If running Octave
  pkg load statistics % Package must downloaded beforehand!
end %  if

% Calculate likelihood by using binomial
% distribution at each value of p

if true % false yields same, but likelihood is more explicit

  L_p = binopdf( h, N, p ); % Efficient one-liner

else

   % More explicitly shows likelihood rather than probability
   for i_p = 1 : length(p)
     L_p(i_p) = binopdf( h, N, p(i_p) );
   end % for i_p

end % if

% Plot likelihood function
plot( p, L_p, 'o' , 'MarkerFaceColor' , 'b' );
set(gca,'XTick' , 0:0.1:1 );
grid on
xlabel(sprintf( "Probability p of getting heads", p ));
ylabel(sprintf( "Likelihood of p,\ngiven %g head in %G flips", h, N ));
```

[image]